# Python recursive aggregation

Tags: python, recursion, arraylist, aggregate

I am working with a nested data structure which needs to be flattened. The values need to be aggregated so totals are produced across each level of the nested data. I'm trying to do this recursively but it's not clear how best to achieve this?

The following is an example of the data I'm working with.

```
def get_result():
    return {
        "a1": {
            "b1": {
                "c1": {
                    "d1": 1,
                    "d2": 1,
                },
                "c2": {
                    "d3": 1,
                }
            },
            "b2": {
                "c3": {
                    "d4": 1
                }
            }
        },
        "a2": {}
    }
```

The data I'd like to produce would be as follows:

```
[
    {
        "key": "a1",
        "total": 4
    },
    {
        "key": "b1",
        "total": 3
    },
    {
        "key": "c1",
        "total": 2
    },
    {
        "key": "d1",
        "total": 1
    },
    {
        "key": "d2",
        "total": 1
    }
    {
        "key": "c2",
        "total": 1
    },
    {
        "key": "d3",
        "total": 1
    },
    {
        "key": "b2",
        "total": 1
    },
    {
        "key": "c3",
        "total": 1
    },
    {
        "key": "d4",
        "total": 1
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursion

```
from collections import defaultdict

def agg(data):
    result = defaultdict(int)
    agg_sum = 0
    for k, v in data.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            d, sub = agg(v)
            if sub:
                result.update(d)
                result[k] += sub
                agg_sum += sub
        else:
            result[k] += v
            agg_sum += v
    return result, agg_sum
```

Comment: I suggest adding `from collections import defaultdict` at the beginning of the code, and a link to [the documentation on defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive generator function for a shorter solution:

```
d = {'a1': {'b1': {'c1': {'d1': 1, 'd2': 1}, 'c2': {'d3': 1}}, 'b2': {'c3': {'d4': 1}}}, 'a2': {}}
def get_aggr(d):
   return d if not isinstance(d, dict) else sum(map(get_aggr, d.values()))

def aggr_keys(d):
   for a, b in d.items():
      yield {'key':a, 'total':get_aggr(b)}
      yield from (() if not isinstance(b, dict) else aggr_keys(b))

print(list(aggr_keys(d)))
```

Output:

```
[{'key': 'a1', 'total': 4}, 
 {'key': 'b1', 'total': 3},  
 {'key': 'c1', 'total': 2}, 
 {'key': 'd1', 'total': 1}, 
 {'key': 'd2', 'total': 1}, 
 {'key': 'c2', 'total': 1}, 
 {'key': 'd3', 'total': 1}, 
 {'key': 'b2', 'total': 1}, 
 {'key': 'c3', 'total': 1}, 
 {'key': 'd4', 'total': 1}, 
 {'key': 'a2', 'total': 0}]
```